# How to connect applet launched in webpage to a datasource in weblogic

Tags: java, database, exception, applet, datasource

I have created two projects in NetBeans one is a JSF (web) and a Java application that has an applet.

I want to launch the applet from JSF (which so far I have managed) but I am unable to make the applet connect to a datasource name that I have created in weblogic where I have deployed the JSF. When I try
to connect to the datasource from applet this is the error that I am getting:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to 
    specify class name in environment or system property, 
    or as an applet parameter, 
    or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

### Code

```
Connection conn;
DataSource
try
{
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ds = ((DataSource)ctx.lookup("mydatasource"));
conn=ds.getConnection();
System.out.println("connection established");
}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
}
```

Where could I be going wrong or what am I missing.

Comment: First of all, are you very well aware that an applet is basically a piece a Java code which runs physically at the same machine as where the webbrowser runs (the client) and thus not at the one as where the webserver with the databaseserver runs (the server)?

Comment: @Balus so its is not possible to do that? Ok What I want to achieve is that I don't want to hard code database connection in the applet what other methods can use to connect  without hardcoding database connection connection within the applet

Comment: It's surely possible, but not the way you incorrectly assumed (DB is not in client side, but in server side).

Comment: @BalusC how can achieve this?

Comment: @BalusC how can I make the applet to connect to a datasource